# Check for substring in Shell without Bashisms

Tags: regex, linux, shell, dash-shell

I'm trying to write a shell script, and in it I have to look for the presence of **-32** in a string. Unfortunately I have to do it without using any bashisms as it has to run on computers running Dash.

I tried `case ${1+"$@"} in *-32*);;` but that will pick up something like **-321**. Is there a way to use a regex or something to look for just that  flag? It can have other flags around it separated by spaces in the string.

I think the regex I would need looks for -32 with either a space or end of line after. `-32(\s|$)`

I'm pretty new to regexes so I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you loop over the arguments instead of treating them as one string?

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but how would I do that?

Comment: `for arg; do if [ "X$arg" = "X-32" ] ...; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` with word boundary:

```
grep -E '-32\b' FILE
```

`\b` matches at a 'word boundary' = the location between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character.

In the default locale, an 'alphanumeric character' (as the term is used  above) means any character that is matched by the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (i.e. any number, any of the letters A–Z and underscore).

In an analogous way `\B` matches wherever there is *not* a word boundary (i.e. any location where the characters on either side of it are of the same type, either both alphanumeric characters, or both non-alphanumeric).

So if you wanted to make sure that the minus sign must be *preceded* by a non-alphanumeric character (e.g. space), as well, you would write the following:

```
grep -E '\B-32\b' FILE
```

This will match `xx -32 xx` (with a space before the minus) but *not* `xx-32 xx` (without the space). Since space and minus are both non-alphanumeric `\B` will match between them, but `\b` will not.

If you wanted to make sure that the minus sign is preceded by a alphanumeric character instead, you would write the following:

```
grep -E '\b-32\b' FILE
```

Which matches e.g. `x-32 x` (without the space), but not `x -32 x` (with a space before the minus).

Answer (score 1):

All these examples use *only* builtin functions, and are completely compatible with `dash`.

## Finding Substrings

If you're actually looking for a substring of a string you can use `case` or `if`.

Let me illustrate by writing two different `match` functions using each. If you're lazy you can cut/paste anyone of these functions into your script and use:

```
if match -32 "$STRING"; then
    echo "found '-32'!"
fi
```

E.g. if you wanted to search for `$SUBSTR` at both beginning and end, and separated from the rest of the string by spaces you could use something like this:

```
function match() {
    local SUBSTR="$1" STR="$2"                # get args
    case " $STR " in                          #   add extra spaces
        *" $SUBSTR "*) return 0 ;;            #   return true if match
    esac
    return 1                                  # no match: return false
}
```

(In the above function I add space around `$STR` so I don't have to explicitly look for matches at the beginning and end of the string.)

```
function match() {
    local SUBSTR=" $1 " STR=" $2 "            # get args + add extra spaces
    [ "${STR#*"$SUBSTR"}" != "$STR" ] \
        && return 0                           # match: return true
    return 1                                  # no match: return false
}
```

This `if` statement is a little trickier. The expression `${STR#*"$SUBSTR"}` part mean, take `$STR`, and remove everything from the beginning of it, up to the first occurrence of `$SUBSTR` (if `$SUBSTR` couldn't be found, don't remove anything). Then we compare that with the original `$STR` and if they are *not* the same, we know the substring was found.

## Finding an argument

Now, if you're actually looking for an argument, you could use any of the above functions, and then simply use `match "-32" "$*"`, but would find all substrings, and not distinguish the arguments from each other (e.g. in the unlikely event that any argument, such as a filename, happened to *contain* the string ' -32 ' that would match).

Better to just look at the args in that case. Again I'll write a little function for you that you can call with `argmatch "$ARG" "$@"`

```
argmatch() {
    local FIND="$1" ARG; shift               # get $FIND arg, remove it from $@
    for ARG; do                              # loop $@
        [ "$ARG" = "$FIND" ] && return 0     #   found? then return true
    done
    return 1                                 # return false
}
```